# PUT Method to server java

Tags: java, android, put

I have tried sending message to server with PUT method but it doesn't work. 
Server replies : The server encountered an error processing the request. See server logs...

```
String result = null;
        InputStream inputStream = null;
        try {

            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPut httpPut = new HttpPut(url);
            httpPut.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

            Log.v("Execute: ", httpPut.getRequestLine().toString());

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpclient.execute(httpPut);
            inputStream = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();
            if (inputStream != null) {
                result = convertInputStreamToString(inputStream);
                Log.v("POST CM: ", "result\n" + result);
            } 
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return result;
```

Comment: Could you add the server logs ?

Comment: The server encountered an error processing the request. See server logs for more details.

Comment: Have you tested the PUT call manually using a rest client outside of your application to make sure the problem is not on the API?

Comment: yes i tested with postman and server replay true.

Comment: PUT should deliver something to server. PUT should not expect anything from server except response code

Comment: method PUT is good but JSONObject doesn't. Thx. Now it work!

Comment: Maybe your server doesn't accept PUT method requests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This my HttpPut it work, put usually to update web's data , your put without Entity to update something, if you want to get input stream usually use HttpGet . This is my thinking.

```
public static synchronized void API(String URL, JSONObject uploadata, Context context)
    {
        try {
            URL = URL + "/" + uploadata.get("id") + "?";
            HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
            int timeoutConnection = 30000;
            HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters,
                    timeoutConnection);
            int timeoutSocket = 30000;
            HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutSocket);
            uploadata.put("token", NetworkUtilities.Get_token(null, context));
            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);
            LOG.d("DEYU", "" + 1);
            HttpPut put = new HttpPut(URL);
            LOG.d("DEYU", "" + 2);
            put.addHeader(new BasicHeader("content-type", "application/json"));
            put.setEntity(new StringEntity(uploadata.toString(), HTTP.UTF_8));
            LOG.d("DEYU", "" + 3);
            HttpResponse resp = httpClient.execute(put);
            LOG.d("DEYU", "" + 4);
            String state = String.valueOf(resp.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
            LOG.d("DEYU", "!" + state);
            if (state.equals("200")) {
                reSetDirty(uploadata.getString("user_id"), context);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOG.d("DEYU ", "Put error" + e);
        } finally {
            LOG.d("finally", "finally");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public String makeServiceCall(String url, int method, List<NameValuePair> params)
{
    try
    {
        // http client
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpEntity httpEntity = null;
        HttpResponse httpResponse = null;

        // Checking http request method type
        if (method == POST)
        {
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            // adding post params
            if (params != null)
            {
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));
            }

            httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

        }
        else if (method == GET)
        {
            // appending params to url
            if (params != null)
            {
                String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
                url += "?" + paramString;
            }
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

            httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);

        }
        httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        response = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);

    }
    catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (ClientProtocolException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return response;

}
```

To use PUT method to Send Message to Web Server use NameValuePair :

```
    List<NameValuePair> myProfileList = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(7);
    try
    {
        myProfileList.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Name", "Your Name"));
        myProfileList.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Age", "Your Age "));  
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```